# Append row span on the basis of number of data items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wriiten below lines of jQuery code

```
                 var rowspan = 2;

                   if(data.length == 5 || data.length == 6)
                   {
                       rowspan = 3; 
                   }
                   else if(data.length == 7 || data.length == 8)
                   {
                       rowspan = 4; 
                   }
                   else if(data.length == 9 || data.length == 10)
                   {
                       rowspan = 5; 
                   }
                   else if(data.length == 11 || data.length == 12)
                   {
                       rowspan = 6; 
                   }
                   else if(data.length == 13 || data.length == 14)
                   {
                       rowspan = 7; 
                   }

                  tdDataImage = '<td id="image-td" rowspan="'+rowspan+'">'+
                     '<img class="regCardPhoto" src="'+ imagePath + '">' +
                  '</td>';
```

I am trying to append row span to a td dynamically on the basis of data.length. The above code is working fine. But I am not able to recreate the code for the above logic in a more smart way. For e.g if after 
some days or months data.length might be 15 16 ... or more than 14. Then I will have to write one more else if condition. I am not able to re write the above code in more smarter way.

Comment: sorry i have updated my question

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```js
var rowspan = Math.ceil(data.length * 0.5);
```

If I look at your code it seems that the `rowspan` is about half of the length of the `data`.
To make sure you get a round number I use `Math.ceil` to round the number up.

For example:

```
data.length = 33;
var rowspan = Math.ceil(33 * 0.5); // 33 * 0.5 = 16.5; 16.5 rounded up is 17
```